# Delay an operation

Tags: vhdl

If i connect 3 components together, say they are BRAM read, arithmetic operation and comparison
On a rising_edge are all 3 operations performed?
How do i make sure only 1 operation is performed per clock cycle?

Comment: Without more details, it's hard to give an answer tailored to your situation. Offhand, a finite state machine would work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for sounds like **pipelining**. This is achieved by implementing a state machine where each operation is linked to a state. This way you can either delay them as described in your question by a fixed number of clock cycles or sometimes a new operation should not start before the last one is finished.
This technique is often used to implement more complex arithmetic operations which "cannot" be executed in one clock cycle.

Comment: How can you delay the state machine by bounding different inputs to the same state?

Comment: From my understanding, the state machine essentially has a clock connected to the register of the statemachine which is outputted on each clock cycle

Comment: You would not bound different inputs to the same state, or I get you wrong. The simplest state machine would be one that is linked to a counter to jump from step to step. At counter 0 you perform your first operation and the counter is incremented, then at counter 1 you perform the next operation and so on...

Comment: Ohh so do you mean use a state machine counter to control the operations of circuits?
So some components may only perform on some integer counts but not others?

Comment: That's what pipelining is yes